# CPU fan speed error detected

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, fan, cooling

I'm currently experiencing issues connecting my water cooler (Fractal Design Kelvin S36) to my motherboard (ASUS X99-PRO/3.1). The issue appeared after "waking my pc up". It worked fine yesterday.

After I found out the pc was slow and not responding, I rebooted and checked the CPU temperature in BIOS which showed 94 degrees celcius. After exiting BIOS, I got an error message in POST, saying: "CPU fan speed error detected".

Things I've tried: - Changing the water cooler to a different one (Kraken X61) - Connecting regular fans to the CPU_HEADER (the fans spins just fine) - Resetting BIOS

Hardware:
- ASUS X99-PRO/3.1
- Fractal Design Kelvin S36 / Kraken X61 (the one I tested with)
- Intel Core i7-5930k
- Crucial DDR4 16GB

Software:
- Windows 10 Home (64bit)

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use a utility that's been around forever to assess hardware issues.  It's called SpeedFan. With it running, it reports CPU, MB, and ambient temps, fan speeds, and power consumption. You can also use it to tweak fan speeds if you so desire.

Right off the bat, I would suspect that you're not hooking up the CPU cooler pump to the right 'fan' pins.  My Antec Kuehler specified the CPU fan connector for the pump, and a case fan connection for the radiator fans.  Also make sure you're installing the driver software for the cooler, because that is what takes control of the pump and fan speeds and regulates temperature.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. The thing is, I've had this PC for almost 2 years now, with the software installed - no issues like this until just now. The fans are working fine, and I suspect it's something with my motherboard.

Comment: OK. Your question did not make clear that this was an existing setup that has gone south, instead it appeared to be a new component being installed that worked for a little while, and then quit.  You might consider clarifying that.  Also, you mentioned that your problems started after you put the comp in sleep mode - I've had enough issues with "sleep" vs power down that I never use it on my systems anymore.